# add a formula in a footer of excel and have it update automatically when cell range is changed

Tags: vba, excel

I have added a VBA in excel and it says:

```
Public Sub SetFooter()
    Dim ws As Worksheet

    Application.ScreenUpdating = False

    For Each ws In Worksheets
        ws.Select
        With ActiveSheet
            .PageSetup.CenterFooter = Evaluate("=SUM($J$6:$J$28)")
            .PageSetup.LeftFooter = Evaluate("=average($J$6:$J$28)")
        End With
    Next
End Sub
```

How to get the formula to change automatically when I change the value in the cell?

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to loop through all the sheets to change the footer. You can use the `Workbook_SheetChange` event. Whenever there is a change in the respective range in a particular sheet, the footer of that sheet will get automatically updated.

This code goes in `ThisWorkbook`

```
Private Sub Workbook_SheetChange(ByVal Sh As Object, ByVal Target As Range)
    Dim rng As Range

    Set rng = Range("$J$6:$J$28")

    If Not Intersect(Target, rng) Is Nothing Then
        With Sh.PageSetup
            .CenterFooter = Evaluate("=SUM($J$6:$J$28)")
            .LeftFooter = Evaluate("=average($J$6:$J$28)")
        End With
    End If
End Sub
```

[image]